# Can't compile C89 with array of pointers

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, c89

I'm trying to compile my C89 code that includes an array of pointers to locations in various other arrays.  I keep getting `ERROR (207) Aggregate or union objects may be initialized with constant expressions only`, probably because of how I'm defining it at initialization but I don't really have a better way to do it except defining it one index at a time, which I'd prefer to avoid.  I've tried everything I can think of, is there any way to get around defining it one line at a time?

```c
uint8_t * keyPtrs[] = {
    towers,
    towers,
    *(towers + 1),
    *(towers + 1),
    *(towers + 2),
    *(towers + 2),
    allianceStack
};
```

Comment: This is just not allowed in C89, you will have to define the array and then use assignment statements. In fact this particular initializer is not allowed in any version of the language because `towers` and `*(towers + 1)` can't both be convertible to `uint8_t *`. Maybe you meant `*towers` for the first two entries

Comment: I thought that you didn't need the asterisk on towers because it's an array (sorry if that wasn't clear)

Comment: well `towers` and `*towers` are different things. If it's an array, then one is the array and the other is the first element of the array

Comment: You might be thinking of the fact that `towers` and `&towers` have the same value, which is a different thing, but even then they aren’t interchangeable.

Comment: It would improve the question to show the definition of `towers`, [Help Center > Asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C89 the initializers for an array must be computable at compile-time. [See here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/constant_expression) for a more detailed definition.

In later versions of the language standard this requirement was relaxed for automatic arrays (but remains for static arrays).

You will have to use assignment statements, or otherwise, to fill in values that are not known until runtime.

Answer (score 1):

If the array is supposed to identify elements within a static array `towers`, the proper syntax would be:

```
uint8_t * keyPtrs[] = {
    towers,
    towers,
    towers + 1,
    towers + 1,
    towers + 2,
    towers + 2,
    allianceStack
};
```

The addresses used in such an array should be statically computable if `towers` and `allianceStack` are both array objects with static duration.  It's possible some compilers targeting obscure linkers might might not be able to support static computation of `(ptrConst+intConst)` expressions, but your problem here is almost certainly the incorrect asterisks.